# Detection of groups

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

After having used `bwconncomp` and `regionprops` to detect the number and place of connected domains within my picture. I now want to figure out how much space (size of a convex domain) the objects fill out.

If all of the objects are evenly distributed or are in one big group, this is not a problem as I can just use `convhull` to calculate the area.
The problem is now if I have several groups then I want several convex areas - one for each group, the number of groups are on beforehand unknown.

See for instance: [image]
<sub>(source: [jasonyianakis.co.nz](http://jasonyianakis.co.nz/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/different-people-groups.jpg))</sub>

Note that it is just the grouping I am interested in, the detection as a single element is already functioning.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `'ConvexArea'` property in [`regionprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html)

For example

```
img = imread('http://jasonyianakis.co.nz/wp-ontent/uploads/2012/08/different-people-groups.jpg');
img = im2double(img); %// convert to double
bw = max(bsxfun(@rdivide,img,sum(img,3)),[], 3 )>.4; %// get a binary mask
```

The resulting binary mask:

[image]
Label each component, and get the `'ConvexArea'`:

```
lb = bwlabel(bw);
st = regionprops(lb,'ConvexArea');
cxArea = [st.ConvexArea];
```

Discard too small regions

```
cxArea( cxArea < 100 ) = [];
```

Now you have the convex area of the components:

```
cxArea =
  474813     2054497      451879
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `kmeans` function of Matlab. This funtion is used to divide data into some clusters. Also, *Gaussian mixture models* are frequently used for your purpose (they give the best results).There are lot of information in web about them and several functions implemented in Matlab.

PS: Determine the number of clusters is a very difficult task. `clusterdata` and similar functions can do it for you but it does not mean that it will be the best result. It is usual to try several different number of groups and see what fits best , the *Gaussians* can help, with its weights . If one has a very low weight it is more likely than it is not significant and can be deleted.

Comment: If you don't understand the 'kmeans' function I can pass you an example that I did in a course.

Comment: I'm sorry that I wasn't clear in my problem description. The number of groups are not known beforehand, so I cannot directly apply the kmeans function.

Comment: Then `clusterdata`function of Matlab may be perfect for you. Otherwise _Gaussian Mixture models_ are very useful but more difficult to implement.